# T-SQL opposite of UnionAggregate to disaggregate a multipoint table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, geometry, geospatial, spatial

What is the opposite query statement of:

```
SELECT geometry::UnionAggregate([geom]) FROM pointtable
```

pointtable is a table with millions of points stored as geometry. Since there are lots of points with identical location I use UnionAggregate to create a multipoint (=all locations in one row) layer, ergo all duplicate points are aggregated. How can I reverse/DisAggregate the multipoint layer into one point per row again?

```
Select Distinct
```

does not work on geometry.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Let's say that you had a million points and after the UnionAggregate you had 100k. Would you want to get the 100k points or the one million?

Comment: i want to get the 100k distinct points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you ultimately just want the list of distinct points. Assuming that you have a numbers table, here's what I'd do:

```
select @g.STPointN(n.n)
from dbo.Numbers as n
where n.n <= @g.STNumPoints();
```

Where @g is the result of your UnionAggregate.

Comment: I have found a way to use UnionAggregate and then splitting the Multipoint again -> https://alastaira.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/splitting-multi-geometries-into-single-geometries/

Comment: Yep. The above is essentially approach #2 from that post.